# How to access a file from one computer to another?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, networking, data-binding

I made a c# application that works with sql server 2012. Now that all works on my computer. I installed setup of my c# application on my friends computer. Now i want to access that database which is placed on my PC.
**Questions:**

1- I used wireless evo device to make computer to be on same network. As i shared one computer to other, it asks me to enter user name and password. I entered username and password of my evo device but it generated an error that password & username is invalid.What to enter in these two fields??

2- If it's not a valid way i described above to connect computers. **THEN HOW TO ACCESS SQL SERVER DATABASE that's placed on my computer from my friends computer?**

Comment: I don't understand your comment. @Blam

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the SQL Server location in the connection string in your application. For example:

```
"Server=ServerName\InstanceName;Database=dataBase;User Id=userName;Password=password;"
```

Please refere to this page for specific connection string format for your environment:
[SQL Server 2012 connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/)